# Get base url from a link

Tags: ruby, regex

I tried but was unable to do so. I want to get the base url from a link. To make my question clear here's the example:

Link1: `http://thechangelog.com/rawler-crawl-your-website-and-find-broken-links-with-rub/`

Base url1: `http://thechangelog.com`

Link2: `https://www.facebook.com/BreakingBad`

Base url2: `https://www.facebook.com`

Comment: What's the "base url" for `https://username:password@something.tld:443/path?query_string#fragment_id`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this using the URI module: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI("http://thechangelog.com/rawler-crawl-your-website-and-find-broken-links-with-rub/")
puts "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}"
```

The URI API is the same in v1.9.3 as well, so you should be able to do the same in older versions of Ruby, or JRuby if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

`'(http)(s?)(://)([^/]*)'`

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://thechangelog.com/rawler-crawl-your-website-and-find-broken-links-with-rub/')
base = "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}"
```